# Windows 'windows' folder taking too much disk space

Tags: windows-10, storage

The windows folder on C: drive on windows 10 is taking too much space. I have only 2 GB remaining after running all possible clean up tools and methods. I ran the task schedulers **StartComponentCleanup** tool, and **Dism.exe** as instructed in the [msdocs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/clean-up-the-winsxs-folder?view=windows-10).

Here's what I got from windirstat.
[windirstat image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tX6YT.png)

Is there any way I can reduce the windows folder size without deleting any essential components of the OS? I am running extremely low on storage space. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you believe that the Windows folder is taking "too much space" the system requirements for Windows 10 64-bit is around 20 GB. If you have run the DISM commands to uninstall previously installed cumulative patches then you have done everything you can do. You really DO NOT want to delete or otherwise modify the WinSxS directory as it's required essential component for a stable system.

Comment: Ok. I understand. I'll just increase the disk space and work with it.

Comment: The System32 directory has VERY LITTLE in it.  Those files are mostly hard links to files located in your WinSxS folder which WinDirStat isn't smart enough to know about so it counts them twice.  55gb for your windows drive is your real problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `C:\Windows` folder is actually quite modest - mine is at a whopping
46 GB, but I probably have installed more software components.

One folder you can empty is `C:\Windows\Temp`, where you can delete
any files or folders for which you have the delete permission.

Having only 2 GB free space borders on too little, which might be
insufficient to do a major Windows update. You should try to have
more space. Below are some ideas.

- Getting a larger disk is the simplest solution that involves the least
  modifications
- Adding a second disk and relocating some large folders to it,
  is also quite easy. The `Documents` folder is probably the likeliest
  to gain space, see
  [Quickly Move My Documents to Another Drive in Windows 10](https://www.ubackup.com/synchronization/move-my-documents-to-another-drive-windows-10-6988.html).
- Software products install by default to `C:\Program Files` and
  `C:\Program Files (x86)`, but there is not any constraint to do so.
  You can reinstall some large products in another disk.
- If you can't have a second disk, you could get a USB external disk
  and backup to it some relatively static data.